# How to get details from a single object (local JSON) in a detail page Angular 9

Tags: angular, parameters

I have this JSON object:

```
[
    {
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Apple",
            "price": "free",
            "imageURL": "assets/apples.jpg",
            "category": "Fruits"
        },
      and so on...
```

Im trying to get a detail page like this:

HomeTS

```
categories: any;
  products: Product[]=[];
  filteredProducts: Product[]=[];
  category: string;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
          this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
            console.log(params);
          this.category = params['categories'];
          forkJoin([this.getCategories(), this.getProducts()]).subscribe(() =>  {

              this.filteredProducts=(this.categories && this.category)? 
              this.products.filter(p=> p.category.toLowerCase()===this.category.toLowerCase()) :
              this.products; 
              console.log(this.filteredProducts)
          });

         })
      }

      public getCategories(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.dataService.getCategories().pipe(map(categories => {
          this.categories = categories[0]['categories']
          return true;
        }));
      }
      public getProducts(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.dataService.getProducts().pipe(map(p => {
          this.products = p[0]['products']
          console.log(this.products)
          return true;
        }));
      }
```

Home HTML

```
            <div *ngFor="let c of categories">
                <a  
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  
                routerLink='/home' 
                [queryParams]='{categories: c.name}'
                [class.active]="category===c.name">
                    {{c.name}}
                </a>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let f of filteredProducts">
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <img [src]="f.imageURL" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body" >
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{f.name}}</h5>
                  <a [routerLink]="['/detail',f.id]" class="btn btn-primary">See more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
```

Detail.TS

```
id: any;
  product:any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(switchMap(params => {
      this.id = params.get('id')
      console.log(this.id)--->Gives me 1, for example
      return this.dataService.getProduct(this.id)
    })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.product = data;
      console.log(this.product) ->gives all the objects...
    })

  }
}
```

And the data service method:

```
public getProduct(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('assets/products.json', id) 
  }
```

The url is good, gives me the id, the detail page appears, but nothing is rendering. I guess may DataService method to fetch the id is somewhat wrong. With normal api's,external, this is how I do it, but with local JSON's is it different? Also my routes are correctly configured `detail/:id`

EDIT:@pc_coder: if i put this on the html `{{id}}` I get something like

[image]

Comment: Are you trying get or post metthod?

Comment: @pc_coder  
its a get method, you can see it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-jvve2t)Are you looking for something like that ?

```
public getProduct(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('/assets/products.json/').map( (res: Response) => res[0].products.filter(x=>x.id==id));
  }
```

Comment: so this is the code block inside the getProduct on data service?

Comment: yes right . U need to append url search parameter to id  with correct name in json file

Comment: this line ` { search: params }) ` gets redish

Comment: use params:params if your angular version more than 4

Comment: the first params(key) is still red. Other thing: like i have, my original code, i put on the html somthing like `{{id}}` it gives me the correct id

Comment: why do I get all objects instead of just one?

Comment: ok, now im getting only one object, the selected one, but if I type in the HTM `{{product.name}}` i get nothing

Comment: thanks mate, I just needed to iterate over product...now everything is fine. Many thaks